# Create global object in Azure WCF project

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I believe this is a WCF question, but perhaps it's also related to Azure.  I have a WCF project that executes some iron python scripts.  I'd like to keep a cache of the compiled scripts, so they will not need recompiled each time.

When these scripts run the first time, they can sometimes take 2 or 3 seconds.  However, the next time they run, they will execute in just a few milliseconds.  I would like to cache the script source so it is only compiled once, then reused for anyone who uses my service.  Currently, my entire service behavior is instantiated each time someone connects to my service.  Is there a way to have my ScriptCache object be persistant for the life of the Application?

Below is some sample code that I'm playing with.

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class Foo: IFoo {
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    Dictionary<string, ScriptHost> ScriptCache = new Dictionary<string, ScriptHost>();
    public fooBar doSomething() {
         ...
         for (int editIndex = 0; editIndex < Edits.Count; editIndex++) {
            ScriptHost mCurrentScript;
            if (!ScriptCache.TryGetValue(Edits[editIndex], out mCurrentScript)) {
               mCurrentScript = new ScriptHost(LoadScriptFromStorage(Edits[editIndex]), Edits[editIndex], engine);
               ScriptCache.Add(Edits[editIndex], mCurrentScript);
            }
            mEditTimer.Start();
            mCurrentScript.runScript(mCurrentObj);
            mEditTimer.Stop();
            WriteToLog(mJobID, "Edit: {0}\tTime: {1}", Edits[editIndex], mEditTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            mEditTimer.Reset();
            mEditTimer.Start();
            mCurrentScript.runScript(mCurrentObj);
            mEditTimer.Stop();
            WriteToLog(mJobID, "Edit: {0}\tTime: {1}\t2nd run", Edits[editIndex], mEditTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            mEditTimer.Reset();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to simply mark the properties as static.  I'm going to guess that is's possible that this code could be call in parallel, so you'll need to make sure that the adding to the dictionary is thread safe.  I've included a code snippet below.  I'd replace the call to `ScriptCache.Add` with a call to something like the `AddToCache` function below

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    static ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    static Dictionary<string, ScriptHost> ScriptCache = new Dictionary<string, ScriptHost>();
    static object _dictionaryLock = new object();

    static void AddToCache(string edit, ScriptHost host)
    {
        lock (_dictionaryLock)
        {
            if (!ScriptCache.ContainsKey(edit))
            {
                ScriptCache.Add(edit, host);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfect.  It acted as if the entire class was being instantiated each call.  I figured (if that were the case), even the static objects would have been recreated.  +1...thanks for the help!